# Excel Question on IF Nested Function. Don't know why an element is appearing in the code

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

While I am learning Nested Function with Excel, I encountered a question that I would like to ask.

The criteria is the following:

1. Increase the backers_count by 5 if:
2. The launched_at_month is **January** OR **September**
3. The city is **Vancouver** AND the country_trimmed is **Canada**
4. If these conditions are not met, the backers_count stays the same.
   The code is below:

```
=IF(OR(condition1,condition2), IF(AND(condition3,condition4), backers_count+5, **backers_count**), backers_count)
```

My question is why have another backers_count as show bold in the code given another backers_count if False in the end. I removed it for test and returned with false.

Thank you very much for your help and assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `IF` statement consists of three pieces: *Check*, *Value_if_true*, *Value_if_false* that have to be defined. If you leave the *Value_if_false* part of the inner `IF` statement empty, Excel would show **False** if the first `IF` clause is evaluated to true and the second to false.

As you only want to increase the backers_count if all four conditions are met, you could also come along with a single IF statement:

```
=IF(AND(OR(condition1,condition2),condition3,condition4), backers_count+5, backers_count)
```